# Two lines of 12-pt Times New Roman Bold in an otherwise standard document

Tags: fonts, postscript

I need to able to write two short lines of bold, centered, 12-point Times New Roman in an otherwise standard document (I'm using the book class with the 11pt option).  Can anyone help me?

Thoughts: Since I'm using latex + dvips + ps2pdf, it seems like the simplest way to handle this would be to write a small eps file and include it as a graphic.  As a possible alternative, I seem to recall that there is some way to directly include postscript commands. Unfortunately, I am way out of my depth when it comes to writing postscript of any sort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you just change locally the font to Times New Roman?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
\begin{center}\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries
Two lines of centered text\\in Times New Roman 12pt
\end{center}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
\end{document}
```

If you really  need the system font Times New Roman, you can easily access it with XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
\begin{center}\fontspec{Times New Roman}\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries
Two lines of centered text\\in Times New Roman 12pt
\end{center}
Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.
\end{document}
```

To use XeLaTeX, you may need to change a little your preamble (mainly things like `\usepackage[...]{intputenc}`) but everything which worked with dvips > ps2pdf should work with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Heh. Looks like we answered this at exactly the same time with exactly the same solution (well, almost: I didn't use `\fontsize` and I used `\fontseries{b}` before the `\selectfont` rather than `\bfseries`). Still, I'll delete my answer. Yours has a picture!

Comment: Is that really Times New Roman, or just some form of Times?  (I can't tell the difference, but the publisher that is requiring this might be able to.)

Comment: @Charles: It's Times New Roman (the typeface), but in the Nimbus Roman variant (from URW) which comes with LaTeX. Your publisher will only see a difference if he looks at the fonts embedded in the PDF and wonders why he doesn't see one called `TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT`. In that case, you should try with XeLaTeX (see the update to my answer) which works well with eps figures and pstricks. If XeLaTeX is not an option, you could produce your eps file with inkscape (http://inkscape.org/) and then include it in your document.